# Adding Material effects to java swing

Tags: java, swing, material-design, netbeans-8, materialize

I am trying to make a Java Swing application using NetBeans 8, and I was wondering if there is any possible way I could apply materialize effects to my Java Swing application. I have already worked with the [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) framework for making a web based application, and I have searched Google to find results, but there are none with "materialize" and "swing" keywords together.

Comment: LookAndFeel theming might be worth inspecting.

Comment: There are some hits for "material design" and "swing", though, e.g. this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31143810/1639625)

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend a…software library…are off-topic for Stack Overflow…" Please edit your question to focus a particular problem. See also [tag:javafx], which has improved [support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx+css?sort=votes&pageSize=15) for [tag:css].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you want to add only the material design effects? you can use a material design library like this:

https://github.com/atarw/washer-chess

https://github.com/atarw/material-ui-swing

This is sample:[image]

I hope, he can help you.

Comment: It seems that the address has moved to this one: https://github.com/atarw/material-ui-swing

Answer (score 3):

I want to add an update.

The material style is imported in Swing with a library called [vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing)

The library has the support also to a Theming System, so now is possible defined new themes and the theme inside the system.

Some of the official theme are:

[image: Material Lite]

[image: Material Oceanic]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, it's pure java without any external libraries.

https://github.com/ibilux/SwingMaterialDesign

[image]
[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ncVp.png)